# Formula seems to be wrong into a PFC application note

Tags: datasheet, rms

Here is the formula that I found into the following application note:

https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/an-1166.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153559aabdf1128

[image]

The formula seems to be fault? Am I wrong?

Does it should be:

$$Iin=\frac{Pin}{\sqrt2*Vinrms}$$

It may be too late for my brain...

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

No, it's not wrong if we are talking about sine waves. For instance, in a purely resistive AC circuit Power = Voltage x Current so if we know power and divide it by RMS voltage we get current and that current is an RMS value. To convert that to peak current we multiply by \$\sqrt2\$.

Comment: Hi, I agree with you ! Why my formula is false ? $$Iinpkmax * Vinpk = Pin(max)$$ so $$Iinpkmax = \frac{Pin(max)}{Vinpk}$$ Ok .... my bad ! I knew that It was too late !

Comment: Because \$P_{max}\$ is twice as high as \$P_{average}\$ whereas for current it's only \$\sqrt2\$.

Comment: LOOOOOOL ! I will put my brain in my head the next time ;)